# Unknown javascript with html links found in my footer.php

Tags: javascript, apache, security

Hello can any tell me what does this code do, because this is something found in the footer of my website, which actually is related to a blackhat SEO. Below how how it exactly look like when it was found. If you could tell me how this came into my footer.php, it would be good.

```
<div id="awesomelinks">
<a href="http://www.361studios.net" style="margin-left:-98901px;" title="Website         Design">Website Design</a>,
<a href="http://www.361studios.net" style="margin-left:-98902px;" title="Website Creation">Website Creation</a>,
<a href="http://www.uslbarcodefy.org" style="margin-left:-96832px;" title="Sports Skills">Sports Skills</a>,
<a href="http://www.uslbarcodefy.org" style="margin-left:-96833px;" title="Sports Technology">Sports Technology</a>,
<a href="http://www.pinkeyegraphics.com" style="margin-left:-80381px;" title="Graphic Design">Graphic Design</a>,
<a href="http://www.pinkeyegraphics.com" style="margin-left:-80382px;" title="Graphic Organizers">Graphic Organizers</a>,
<a href="http://www.ecoeasycontest.com" style="margin-left:-90012px;" title="Wedding Dresses">Wedding Dresses</a>,
<a href="http://www.ecoeasycontest.com" style="margin-left:-90013px;" title="Evening Dresses">Evening Dresses</a>,
<a href="http://www.replica.im" style="margin-left:-96831px;" title="Replica Handbags">Replica Handbags</a>,
<a href="http://www.replica.im" style="margin-left:-96832px;" title="Replica Watches">Replica Watches</a>,
<a href="http://www.wilmstumorgroup.com" style="margin-left:-91131px;" title="WoW Gold">WoW Gold</a>,<a href="http://www.wilmstumorgroup.com" style="margin-left:-91132px;" title="Cheap WoW Gold">Cheap WoW Gold</a>,
<a href="http://www.wilmstumorgroup.com" style="margin-left:-91133px;" title="Buy WoW Gold">Buy WoW Gold</a>,
<a href="http://www.near-field-communications.org" style="margin-left:-88931px;" title="Iphone Apps">Iphone Apps</a>,
<a href="http://www.near-field-communications.org" style="margin-left:-88932px;" title="Android Apps">Android Apps</a>,
<a href="http://www.bluelikejazzthemovie.net" style="margin-left:-97511px;" title="Movie Reviews">Movie Reviews</a>,
<a href="http://www.bluelikejazzthemovie.net" style="margin-left:-97512px;" title="Movie Ratings">Movie Ratings</a>,
<a href="http://www.russianfashionweek.info" style="margin-left:-87722px;" title="Fashion Shoes">Fashion Shoes</a>,
<a href="http://www.russianfashionweek.info" style="margin-left:-87723px;" title="Fashion Bags">Fashion Bags</a>,
<a href="http://www.urban-management.info" style="margin-left:-93871px;" title="Urban Clothing">Urban Clothing</a>,
<a href="http://www.urban-management.info" style="margin-left:-93872px;" title="Urban Art">Urban Art</a>,
<a href="http://www.tacomalutherannw.com" style="margin-left:-89007px;" title="Cooking Guides">Cooking Guides</a>,
<a href="http://www.tacomalutherannw.com" style="margin-left:-89008px;" title="Cooking Tips">Cooking Tips</a>,
<a href="http://www.noshfordosh.com" style="margin-left:-80831px;" title="Luxury Shopping Guides">Luxury Shopping Guides</a>,
<a href="http://www.noshfordosh.com" style="margin-left:-80832px;" title="Luxury Products">Luxury Products</a>,
<a href="http://www.turnerfreemansa.com" style="margin-left:-89512px;" title="CJC 1295">CJC 1295</a>,
<a href="http://www.turnerfreemansa.com" style="margin-left:-89513px;" title="CJC 1295 Reviews">CJC 1295 Reviews</a>

<script>
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){
    e=function(c){
        return(c<a?"":e(parseInt(c/a)))
        +
        ((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))
    };
    if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){
        while(c--)d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);
        k=[function(e){return d[e]}];
        e=function(){return'\\w+'};
        c=1;
    };
    while(c--)if(k[c])
    p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);
    return p;
}('2.1(\'0\').5.4="3";',6,6,'bestlinks|getElementById|document|none|display|style'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely possibilities:

1. you're hosting with some scummy webspace providers that mess with your content (in which case, run);
2. more likely: you've been hacked.

2a. either you are running an application with egregious security holes, or

2b. more likely: the account you use to administer the site (typically by FTP) has been compromised (typically through a client machine that accessed the site). Subject all client machines to multiple AV scans and reinstall the OS on any where anything is detected (AV is awful at removal; nuke it from orbit, it's the only way to be sure). Change passwords, ensure FTP is not used (use SFTP instead), delete all code on the server and replace with a known good copy. Inform your hosts in case the compromise originated at a higher level or escalated. If it is your own machine, consider nuking that from orbit too.

Answer (score 0):

### What does this js do?

Well, if you change the `eval` to `alert` or `console.log` you can see that it converts all that nonsense into:

```
document.getElementById('bestlinks').style.display="none";
```

So really, all it is doing is hiding the `bestlinks` element.

### What is the point of it?

There are many possibilities. But take a look at the `bestlinks` element.In your question you have one with the id `awesomelinks`. Maybe this was a mistake made by the malicious person who injected this, unless there is another element with the `bestlinks` id.

As you pointed out, this is clearly blackhat SEO, where it appears they are trying to create a [Link Farm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_farm) with your site as a node, but hide it from you and your users via javascript. It would still show up for search engines, but you and your users would be none-the-wiser.

### How did it happen?

No one can really tell you for sure from StackOverflow. There may be server logs that indicate that your server was compromised, but those can be cleared. Your best bet is to treat the host as a completely compromised machine, and proceed accordingly. My guess would be that it was an automated attack utilizing existing exploits/vulnerabilities in your server and automatically modifying your files. You need to treat the symptom (the modified pages) and ensure that you are safe from future attacks. If you need help setting up a secure server, you should maybe try reading/asking a question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com) as that is off-topic here.